# ASP.NET Core docs/BuildFromSource.md Could not resolve SDK "Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk"

Tags: asp.net-core

(Attempted to add meaningful tags but I am not allowed since I have not used this site sufficiently to earn "reputation points" - a rather odd and not-very-useful restriction)

I'm attempting to build ASP.NET Core from source. I'm following the instructions in `docs/BuildFromSource.md`.

At the step where I run the command `./restore.cmd` from the repository root, I get a number of status lines ending with

```
dotnet-install: Installed version is 9.0.100-alpha.1.23618.1
dotnet-install: Installation finished
```

followed by this

> D:\Repos\aspnetcore\artifacts\toolset\restore.proj : error : Could not resolve SDK "Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk". Exactly one of the probing messages below indicates why we could not resolve the SDK.
> Investigate and resolve that message to correctly specify the SDK.
>
> D:\Repos\aspnetcore\artifacts\toolset\restore.proj : error :   SDK resolver "Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildWorkloadSdkResolver" returned null.
>
> D:\Repos\aspnetcore\artifacts\toolset\restore.proj : error :   Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk (= 9.0.0-beta.23619.4)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v0.0'. PackageSourceMapping is enabled, the following source(s) were not considered: dotnet-eng, dotnet-public, dotnet-tools, dotnet31-transport, dotnet5-transport, dotnet6-transport, dotnet7, dotnet7-transport, dotnet8, dotnet8-transport
> , dotnet9, dotnet9-transport, richnav.
>
> D:\Repos\aspnetcore\artifacts\toolset\restore.proj : error :   MSB4276: The default SDK resolver failed to resolve SDK "Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk" because directory "D:\Repos\aspnetcore.dotnet\sdk
> \9.0.100-alpha.1.23618.1\Sdks\Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk\Sdk" did not exist.
> D:\Repos\aspnetcore\artifacts\toolset\restore.proj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk' specified could not be found.
> Build failed with exit code 1. Check errors above.

My `global.json` file looks like this

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "9.0.100-alpha.1.23618.1"
  },
  "tools": {
    "dotnet": "9.0.100-alpha.1.23618.1",
    "runtimes": {
      "dotnet/x86": [
        "$(MicrosoftNETCoreBrowserDebugHostTransportVersion)"
      ],
      "dotnet": [
        "$(MicrosoftNETCoreBrowserDebugHostTransportVersion)"
      ]
    },
    "Git": "2.22.0",
    "jdk": "11.0.3",
    "vs": {
      "version": "17.2",
      "components": [
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL.ARM64",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.ARM64",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64"
      ]
    },
    "xcopy-msbuild": "17.1.0"
  },
  "msbuild-sdks": {
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk": "9.0.0-beta.23619.4",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Helix.Sdk": "9.0.0-beta.23619.4"
  }
}
```

I have retried following the instructions multiple times including twice from a fresh built machines. Each time I receive the exact same error.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

> I have retried following the instructions multiple times including
> twice from a fresh built machines. Each time I receive the exact same
> error.
>
> How should I proceed?

Well based on your scenari and description, it seems you have done initial troubleshooting in order to investigate your issue.

However, keep in mind there's no exact solution for this kind of exception or build error. What we can do is,  couple of other steps we could follow based on the current scenario.

First of all, could you please double check if the `Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk` installed in correct path. Also, please try installing other versions as well.

Most importantly, you can try clearing the NuGet cache using `dotnet nuget locals --clear all` command which will remove the cache and then try again.

In addition, if after following the above steps still your issue persisted, you can temporarily delete the `global.json` file and retry the restore command.

Finally, please cross check that the the version of `Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk` you are trying is compatible with the version of ASP.NET Core you are trying to build with.

**Note:** The issue might also be related to visual studio version, Operating system and the version you are trying to built with. Please try with the lower compatible version as well.

Comment: Does anyone actually verify BuildFromSource.md with each release?

Some of the problems went away if EVERYTHING is installed on the C: drive, but following BuildFromSource.md EXACTLY still does not work.